# Здрастуйте чи здравствуйте?

Tags: вживання-слів

Словник української мови:

> ЗДРАСТУВАТИ, рідко ЗДРАВСТВУВАТИ, ую, уєш, недок.
>
> 1. Бути здоровим; благополучно існувати...
> 2. наказ. сп. здрастуй (здрастуйте). Вітання при зустрічі...
> 3. наказ. сп. здрастуй (здрастуйте), у знач. виг., фам. Уживається при вираженні здивування, заперечення і т. ін.

Очевидна подібність укр. *здравствувати* з рос. *здравствовать*. Українські філологи зацьковують вживання цього слова і переконують, що воно російське. Можна його й уникати або замінювати синонімами, але на чиєму боці правда?

Comment: Я чув лише «драстуйте», без «з».

Comment: @MarinaJurchenko, Ви питаєте про те, як правильніше — «здра**ст**уйте» або «здра**вств**уйте», — чи Ви питаєте про правильність цього слова, незалежно від наявності оцих -в-, загалом?

Comment: Правильно «дратуті» ☺.

Comment: «Здоров» до коров, а до людей — «Здрастуйте».

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPD. З [коментаря](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/2946/%D0%97%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5/3310?noredirect=1#comment8160_3310) пана @Sasha: в словнику Кримського з Єфремовим це слово є в [прикладах](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B7%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%2A&scope=all&dicts=1&highlight=on).

З одного боку, звісно, ані у [словнику Грінченка](http://hrinchenko.com/takogo-slova-net.html#show_point), ані у [словнику Кримського з Єфремовим і ко](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B7%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B2*&scope=all&dicts=1&highlight=on) такого слова немає.

З іншого боку, у [корпусі української мови](http://www.mova.info/corpus.aspx?l1=209) пише, що таке слово вживають:

[Панас Мирний у романі "Повія"](https://www.ukrlib.com.ua/books/printit.php?tid=982&page=70):

> — Здрастуйте! Гуляєте? — і перед нею, наче з-під землі, виріс
>   Проценко. Вона мовчала.

[Марко Кропивницький у "Дай серцю волю, заведе у неволю"](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=X3ZKDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT6&lpg=PT6&dq=%D0%A9%D0%BE%20%D0%B6%20%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%8F,%20%D1%87%D0%B8%20%D0%B7%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%89%D0%B5?&source=bl&ots=9KxnO0Fpia&sig=9RnwQcXqKWyDk49uxFi5dISF9N4&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiIpvrz5uzZAhXPa5oKHSXeApQQ6AEILDAB#v=onepage&q=%D0%A9%D0%BE%20%D0%B6%20%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%8F%2C%20%D1%87%D0%B8%20%D0%B7%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%89%D0%B5%3F&f=false):

> [Семен:] Що ж бабуся твоя, чи здрастують ще?
>
> [Одарка (жартуючи):] Підскакують; з печі до долу, а з долу на піч.

О. Довженко у фільмі "Земля":

> — Здрастуйте, діду, — почулись дзвінкі дитячі голоси з-за куща калини
>   біля сусідньої могилки.

[Всеволод Нестайко у "Казкових пригодах Грайлика":](https://www.ukrlib.com.ua/books/printit.php?tid=2767&page=15)

> — Здрастуйте, бабусю! — кинувся до неї Грайлик.
>
> — Здрастуй, милий! Вітаю тебе у моєму царстві,— лагідно усміхнулася
>   вона до нього.

Отже, це слово вживають у літературних творах з ХІХ по ХХІ століття, всю історію нової української мови, немає причин вважати його росіянізмом, хоч би яке схоже на російський аналоґ воно не було.

Comment: В живій мові, на півдні Чернігівської області ще й до "Драстуйте" редукується. Вживається дуже часто. Навскид - не менш 70% привітань

Comment: Який логічний зміст слова "Здрастуйте"? Вживання даного слова в часи сильного впливу Російської імперії на Україну для мене не показник. Необхідно копати глибше, шукати докази використання слова за часів козацтва.

Comment: @SergeySerjio необхідно кому?

Answer (score 2):

**Правда на сторонї філолоґів**.

[ЕСУМ](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%B7%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8)

> - очевидно, запозичення з російської мови;
> - р. *здра́вствуй*, як і болг. *здра́сти* «привіт», походить від стсл. *съдравьствоуи*, що пояснюється як скорочення форми 1-ї ос. одн. *съдравьствоуѭ* «поздоровляю» (Соболевский ЖМНП 1897, листопад, 63) або як форма наказового способу від *съдравьствовати* «бути здоровим» (Dickenmann RS 21, 133);

Очевидність, звісно, залишена лише для мовознавцїв, але спробуймо розібрати:

- Тут прямо сказано про запозику з Московської. Я не мовознавець, пак не маю прямих тверджень, але трохи трохи умовно обрїзю і сказю, же запозика з Церковно-Словянською, бо:

  1. Частоуживані відти слова зберегли свою форму.
  2. Московська теж має наступну властивість.

- Видно відсутність [повноголосся](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8F), тобто коли з **or* маємо *oro* за тим ж корньом: Московське *здрав-ие* проти *здоров-и̑а*. Тому якби перенести на Український лад, то було би на зразок *здоровувати*, а отже *здоровуйте*.

Навмисно поки не писав *здоровствувати*, бо цього наростка *-ств-* трїба дослїдити. Хоч воно *може* мати спільність з наростком *-ство*, як в *мастерство*, але однаково постає питаннє доцїльність уживу в дїйословах.

Також зазначу, же є такі вирази:

- **Бути здоров(им)**, має ту ж змислову суть, як вже зазначено в ЕСУМ-і, шчо і *здоровствувати*. І є достатньо уживаним, причому не лише при чханнї, а також при [вітаннях і просчаннях](http://slovopedia.org.ua/47/53399/317367.html), часто без дїйослова *бути* і з укороченим прикметником *здоров*. Існують чимало похідних, наприклад *здоровенькі були*.
- **Зичити [доброго] здоровʼя**, котре уживане в прямому змислї як побажаннє, тому, з мойого досвіду, зазвичай буває як окреме вітаннє чи просчаннє, але не як вітаннє, хоча може десь і так.

- Те саме з **[здоро́витися](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=136966&page=1132)**, з котрого буде *здоровтеся*, шчо значе *почувати ся здоровим*.

Answer (score 1):

відновідь: здрастуйте (здрастувати)

перевіривши за [одним із корпусів](https://mova.institute/bonito/run.cgi/first_form?corpname=zvidusil), я склав таблицю частовживаности:
[image]

висновок на лице. чи є варіант "здравствуйте" суто російським, залишається гадати. але такі складні поєднання приголосних, як "вств" (здра**вств**уйте), не притаманні українській мові.

> Можна його й уникати або замінювати синонімами, але на чиєму боці правда?

правда у тому, що кожний ~10 випадок вживання слів зі списку (у таблиці) – це вживання "здравствуйте".