# Як можна замінити російське "здрасте"

Tags: переклад, from-russian

Російська [Вікіпедія](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B7%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5) каже, що російське слово "здравствуйте" (розмовний варіант "здрасте") - це форма вітання при зустрічі. І мене вже довгий час турбує декілька питань пов'язаних з цим словом.

По-перше, я замінити його в електронних листах (або ж, наприклад, в ставках на проекти на деяких фріланс-біржах)?

По-друге, як замінити саме розмовний варіант слова "здравствуйте"?

Отож, що нам пропонує Інтернет перекладачі:

[Глосб](https://uk.glosbe.com/ru/uk/%D0%B7%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5) дає наступні варіанти:

"**Добрий день**" - мене цей варіант не дуже задовільняє, бо, якщо ми говоримо про перше питання - то ми не можемо бути впевнені о котрій годині буде прочитаний наш лист (просто слово "здравствуйте" в цьому випадку виходить унікальним, адже його можна вживати і ранком, і днем, і ввечері). А саме цієї унікальності у цього варіанта і бракує. Ну стосовно другого питання - загалом, варіанти "добрий день", "добрий ранок", "добрий вечір" можуть бути хорошою відповіддю на російське "здрасте"

**"Привіт"** - тут проблема зовсім інша - є та сама унікальність (адже ми можемо вітатися цим словом в будь-якій годині), але воно надто фамільярне і, на мою думку, його можна вживати в розмові з друзями, родичами або хоча б знайомими. Чи буде воно хорошою відповіддю на російське "здрасте" від незнайомої людини - я не впевнений. Чи можна його вживати в листах, коли ви пишите стосовно роботи - я вважаю, що ні.

Гадаю, що у варіанта "добридень" така ж проблема як і в варіанта "добрий день". Отож чи є таке слово в українській мові, яке можна було б використати для вітання о будь-якій годині дня, незалежно від того чи це якась ділова зустріч, зустріч з друзями чи незнайомцями.

Також я ще наткнувся на статтю "[Скільки способів привітатися в українців](https://osvita.ua/vnz/reports/culture/1173/)", де пишуть, що варіанти «Здрастуй!» / «Здрастуйте!» - це запозичення з російської мови (я також дотримуюсь цієї думки). Ну стосовно варіанту "Здоровенькі були!" - гадаю, що він дуже хороший, однак, знову ж таки, його не можна використати в офіційних листах.

Comment: Загалом, в українській мові є й [здрастуйте](https://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=35840&page=1133). Його вживали Купрієнко, Старицький, Панас Мирний, Франко, Нечуй-Левицький, Кропивницький, Карпенко-Карий, Підмогильний. Хоча цілком можливо, воно запозичене (але це не завжди означає «погане»).

Comment: Related to [Здрастуйте чи здравствуйте?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/2946/%d0%97%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b5) .

Comment: як щодо *вітаю*?

Comment: Sasha, я бачив, що тема про запозичення слова "здрастуйте" вже обговорювалось на форумы, однак, наскільки я зрозумів, до якоїсь згоди там не дійшли. 
@Yola, також я зустрічай цей варіант, справа от в чому - мені здається, що інколи, навіть в мейлі, коли використовується варіант "вітаю", людина може подумати, що я її з чимось хочу привітати. І також, якщо цей варіант розглядати - то наскільки часто він використовується в офіційно-діловому листуванні?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Загалом, як зазначив [Sasha](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/users/4/sasha), за [СУМ-20](https://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=35840&page=1133), *"здрастуйте"* є легітимним українським словом:

> 2
> . наказ. сп. здрастуй
> (
> здрастуйте
> ),
> у знач. виг.
> Вітання під час зустрічі
> . – Здрастуйте, дідусю! – закричало радісно дитя
> (Панас Мирний)
> ;
> – Здрастуйте! – здоровкаються всі до бабусі й, як одно, низенько вклоняються
> (С. Васильченко)
> ;
> – Здрастуй, невідома плането! – урочисто говорив академік .. – Здрастуй, Венеро, загадкова плането таємниць і несподіванок..!
> (В. Владко)
> ;
> – Здрастуй, здрастуй! – лагідно усміхнулася мама. – Леся розказувала мені про тебе
> (В. Нестайко)
> ;
> //
> у знач. ім., невідм.
> – Ніхто не сказав ні “здрастуй”, ні “прощай”, – подумав Максим
> (І. Багряний)
> .

---

**[Синоніми](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%B7%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B9):**

> **ДО́БРИЙ ДЕНЬ** [**ДО́БРОГО ДНЯ** *рідше*] (*привітання при зустрічі*), **ДОБРИ́ДЕНЬ**, **ВІТА́Ю** *розм.*, **ДО́БРОГО ЗДОРО́В’Я** [**ЗДОРО́В’ЯЧКА**] *розм.*, **ЗДОРО́В** [**БУВ**] *розм.*, **ЗДОРО́ВІ БУЛИ́** [**ЗДОРОВЕ́НЬКІ БУЛИ́**] *розм.*, **ЗДРА́СТУЙТЕ ВАМ** *розм.*, **ПРИВІ́Т** *фам.*, **САЛЮ́Т** *фам.*, **ПОМАГА́ЙБІ** *заст.*; **ДО́БРОГО РА́НКУ** [**ДО́БРИЙ РА́НОК** *рідше*] (*уранці*); **ДО́БРИЙ ВЕ́ЧІР**, **ДОБРИ́ВЕЧІР** (*увечері*).

[**ВІТАННЯ**](https://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=14810&page=483) не є по суті синонімом, тому я схильний відкинути як варіант.

Потрібно розділити дані синоніми на офіційні та неофіційні(розмовні) варіанти.

*Офіційні:*

> **ДО́БРИЙ ДЕНЬ** [**ДО́БРОГО ДНЯ** *рідше*] (*привітання при зустрічі*), **ДО́БРОГО РА́НКУ** [**ДО́БРИЙ РА́НОК** *рідше*] (*уранці*), **ДО́БРИЙ ВЕ́ЧІР**, **ДОБРИ́ВЕЧІР** (*увечері*).

*Неофіційні:*

> **ВІТА́Ю** *розм.*, **ДО́БРОГО ЗДОРО́В’Я** [**ЗДОРО́В’ЯЧКА**] *розм.*, **ЗДОРО́В** [**БУВ**] *розм.*, **ЗДОРО́ВІ БУЛИ́** [**ЗДОРОВЕ́НЬКІ БУЛИ́**] *розм.*, **ЗДРА́СТУЙТЕ ВАМ** *розм.*, **ПРИВІ́Т** *фам.*, **САЛЮ́Т** *фам.*.

---

Необхідно зазначити: зазвичай, при написанні листів, [привітанням нехтуюють](https://ukrainskamova.com/publ/chinnij_pravopis/dilova_mova/movni_zasobi_pochatku_j_zavershennja_dilovogo_lista_pochatok_dilovogo_lista/9-1-0-285), надаючи перевагу шанобливим формам звертання(якщо ми говоримо про українську мову). Я припускаю, що тут ви маєте на увазі ділове/офіційне листування, судячи із речення про фамільярність слова "привіт" в листах, крім того, особисто, я не уявляю собі неформальне листування в межах професійного дорослого світу.

---

### Потенційні заміни слову "здрастуйте" в листах(офіційних)

Я був би схильний не погодитися із вами і вживати синоніми в офіційному стилі, котрі були наведені вище, оскільки ніякого правила немає, котре забороняло б так робити або стверджувало, щоб робити так не слід(в українській мові).

Крім того, в українській і немає слова, котре було б офіційним вітанням, яке є не прив'язаним до часу дня.

### Розмовна заміна слову "здрастуйте"

На мою думку, всі слова із неофіційного синонімічного ряду підходять для цього.